# Mobile App and Salesforce Integration

Tags: rest-api, mobile

I am working on a project where I need to Integrate a Mobile app with Salesforce using REST API.
Also we have a chat functionality on mobile app .

My requirement is :All the Chat conversation should be stored in salesfore in a object and it should be displayed in a visualpage in the similar way as it display in mobile app or in chatter.

I have completed the REST API Integration but I am stuck at the point as "How to display the Chat Information on VF page" almost similar to what it is displaying in mobile app .

Comment: Chatter chat, custom chat, live agent chat ?

Comment: thanks Samuel for the reply,I do not want the chatter functionality on the vf Page. I only want that the chat conversation of Mobile should be displayed in the similar format in VF page in saleforce also.

Comment: The thing is, it's a bit unclear what you mean by "chat conversation of mobile".  Is it a custom chat functionality you have built in the app ?

Comment: yes it is custom chat functionality that we have built in mobile App,Now I want to store those conversation in Salesforce in a object and want to display that converstation in a VF page . so for do this, using REST API , I am able to get the converstations in Json Format, But now it is bit hard for me to store that as a record in some object and then display in same format on VF page, as it get displayed in Mobile, .

Answer (score 1):

You're asking 2 separate things. Without much details, context or a specific problem. So i'll give a high level answer.

**1) how to get my custom chat conversations in salesforce**

- You'll need to create one or more custom objects to store chat messages/conversations/.. this could be quite similar to the data structure you're using in your app.
- Are your app users the same as your salesforce users ? Ifnot you may need custom objects here too.
- Access to custom objects is automatically available through the REST API, you could use this to send data into salesforce. Alternatively (if you want to send multiple records/objecys in a single go, you can write custom apex REST services/endpoints.

**2) display my custom chat conversations in salesforce**

- If you have the chat data in custom objects this gets easy. Depending on your data structure you can either use standardcontrollers or a custom apex controller to access your data on a visualforce page.
- You can use the visualforce tag elements to create your page markup, or use custom HTML on a visualforce page if the page needs to have the same look and feel as your mobile app.

Comment: Know that if you're satisfied with an answer you can mark it as such by the (V) button on the left of it.